# SSRS 2008 Break the column in different pages

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am creating a SSRS 2008 Report
       in my report i have 200 columns, it is difficult for visualizing purpose,
     is there any way in SSRS by which i can show 20 column per page with row hearer in each page.

ex..

```
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14 15 .....................
 2010  5  4  8  7  6 
 2011     9  7  5  8  9  4     2  5
 2012  1  2  4  5  3 
 2013
```

can i break to show only 20 columns in first page & reamin 20 second page & show on with column heaer repeat in each page

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your column IDs are sequential, simply set up a new column grouping as `=Floor(Fields!columnID.Value/20)` above your existing column ID grouping and set a page break on your new grouping.

Comment: You can also try different elegant way of `=Fields!columnID.Value Mod 20`